# JavaScript coordinates showing as greater than the image width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to get the location of the mouse while hovering over an image in pixels from the top left corner of the image. I am currently using the `pageX` and `pageY` event attributes but this is returning a value greater than the width and height of the image itself.

```
var getImgCoord = function(e) {
  var x = e.pageX,
      y = e.pageY;
  console.log(x + ' | ' + y);
}
$('.featuredImg').mousemove(function() {
  getImgCoord(event);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apologies, top left corner of the image, I have edited the question above.

Comment: Have you tried `clientX` and `clientY`?

Comment: I did, clientX and clientY produced the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pageX and pageY are the coordinates relative to the top left corner of the *document* not your image itself (the name already says it).

you need to subtract the offsets from your element:

```
$('.featuredImg').mousemove(function(e) {
  var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
      y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
  console.log(x + ' | ' + y);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/D5uuA/

```
var getImgCoord = function(e) {
  var imageOffset = $(this).offset(); 
   //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
   var x = e.pageX - imageOffset.left,
       y = e.pageY - imageOffset.top;
   console.log(x + ' | ' + y);
}
$('.featuredImg').mousemove(getImgCoord);
```

Comment: what is the scope of the getImgCoord function? $(this) will probably be the window object (or whatever the current global scope for getImgCoord is) and therefore your code wont work!